# Dynamically creating PDF document with PSPDFKit

Tags: xamarin.ios, pdf-generation, xamarin, pspdfkit

I am using PSPDFKit as an image editor.

How do I create a new PSPDFDocument with a certain width/height? Also, how do I dynamically add pages to PDPDFDocument?

Maybe the answer is that I need to dynamically create a blank PDF myself every time I want to edit an image. I was hoping it was built in.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can both create new empty files and add/remove documents using [PSPDFProcessor](http://pspdfkit.com/api/Classes/PSPDFProcessor.html). Use the HTML conversion with an empty string to get a blank page; and the `generatePDFFromDocument:` methods to modify existing documents.

Comment: Hi steipete, can you please give few lines of code to add new pages to existing PDF.?? thanks in advance.